# Version label need to be update in Stack Exchange API Authorization page

Tags: bug, api, stackapps, content

In the Authorization for the Stack Exchange API Documentation page, the version is still showing as **V2.0**, since the current version is 2.2 so it should be changed as **V2.2**.

The authorization page is popups when trying to Run any [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-suggested-edits) and clicked the **Get Token** button and you didn't authorized previously.

Screen shot for reference:

> [image: Old Version name showing in the Authorization page]

Comment: Cross-site duplication in [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/7469/37357)